# WPF application starts maximized, but screen resolution does not match display

Tags: wpf, xaml, resolution

I have a WPF application, and define the window in XAML as maximized, and 1080x1920 (1080p vertical format):

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"           
    x:Class="PLBCarousel.MainWindow"
    x:Name="Window"
    Width="1080" Height="1920" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowState="Maximized" KeyDown="Window_KeyDown">
```

When I run the application on a 1080w x 1920h display, with taskbar hidden, it starts maximized, but all the elements are misaligned, and watch window provides the following values:

```
    System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight 1536.0  double
    System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth  864.0   double
```

This application has displayed correctly on the same display in the past, but the screen was used as a secondary display, rather than primary.

Any ideas why this is happening?  I think the above two values should resolve to 1920 and 1080 respectively.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236173/screen-resolution-problem-in-wpf for info on how WPF units relate to pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I needed to change my system DPI, after reinstalling my OS.  Instructions for doing that on Win 7 can be found here: [Win 7 DPI change](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/443-dpi-display-size-settings-change.html).

Thanks to Kristopher Johnson's link above which helped.