# Adapt or Change Layout of WPF controls according to different screen resolution

Tags: .net, wpf, layout, screen-resolution

Is there a control in WPF that let's me define 1 or more layout for a user control based on the window's size.

Say with a resolution of 1280 x 800, I would have a Grid control with 4 columns to display my data, but with a resolution of 800 x 600, I would only a Grid control with 2 columns, so that it does look crushed.

For example

```
<Layouts>
 <Layout x:key="1280x800">
  <Grid/> with 4 columns
 </Layout>
 <Layout x:key="800x600">
  <Grid /> with 2 columns
 </Layout>
</Layouts>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use a `ContentControl` which has it's `Content` or `ContentTemplate` property set via a `DataTrigger` bound to either the [SystemParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemparameters.aspx) of the window, or the `ActualHeight`/`ActualWidth` of the window.

You may also need an [IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx), since Triggers only test if a value is equal to something, and you may need to test if the Screen Height/Width is greater than or less than a particular value.

Also, WPF doesn't actually scale based on screen resolution. To quote [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2236911/302677)

> Keep in mind that all WPF locations and sizes are floating point with
>   a unit of 1/96 inch. Not pixels. **This makes your window designs
>   resolution independent.** Doing the math: height = 960 / 96 = 10 inches.
>   With your video adapter set to 120 DPI (120/96 = 125%): 10 * 120 =
>   1200 pixels. Same for width: 1536 / 96 * 120 = 1920 pixels.

Comment: I like this idea. I'll try that