# Does the TransformToDevice transform in Windows 8.1 change with DPI settings?

Tags: c#, wpf, dpi

I have built a WPF application which has a window that can be docked to the edges of the desktop.  I use the `SHAppBarMessage` WIN32 API to perform the docking functions.

Under Windows 8.1, I've noticed that when docked, the window is only reserving half the width it needs.  My code gets the `PresentationSource` object from the window being docked and then gets the `TransformToDevice Matrix` object:

```
PresentationSource source = PresentationSource.FromVisual( window );
Matrix TransformToDevice = source.CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice;
```

I then use the `Matrix` to transform the window's `ActualHeight` and `ActualWidth` to device coordinates before computing the size of the region on the desktop to reserve for the window:

```
Size windowSize = (Size) source.CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice.Transform( new Vector( appbarWindow.ActualWidth, appbarWindow.ActualHeight ) );
```

All of this code works as long as the display is in 100% DPI mode, but problems rise when you change the DPI setting. In higher DPI settings ( that is, DPI > 100% ), the area being reserved for the window on the desktop is narrower than the window.

In my debugging, I placed a breakpoint on the line that computes the window size above.  I've found that in the 100% DPI setting, the transform `Matrix` is the Identity matrix.  But after changing the DPI setting, the `Matrix` is unchanged!

I thought that this transform matrix would change if the DPI settings changed?  If they don't, how do I get a transform that takes the DPI settings into effect?  Is there a method that I am supposed to call when the DPI settings change?  And if so, how do I get notification of the DPI Setting change?  I have code that is called when the `SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged` event is raised, and it is getting called when the DPI settings change.  But the transforms are always the `Identity Matrix`.  Shouldn't they change?  How do I get the correct transform matrix?

Comment: Does my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236173/screen-resolution-problem-in-wpf/3042339#3042339 help with this at all? I used TransformToDevice() to get DPI values, which are multiplied to PrimaryScreenHeight and PrimaryScreenWidth values.

Comment: You're using code similar to mine.  The problem is that the values in the matrix are not changing with DPI changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out that the short answer to my question is "no."  Windows 8.1 added a new kind of DPI awareness called per-monitor DPI awareness. The WPF code is not per-monitor DPI aware.  It turns out you have to handle per-monitor DPI awareness differently from system DPI awareness, which WPF has built-in.