# Get Screen Scale Factor (100%; 125%)

Tags: c#, screenshot, scale, resolution

i'm using the Code from this question, to save screenshots into a bitmap:
[Capture the Screen into a Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362986/capture-the-screen-into-a-bitmap)

there is one Problem, the line `Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X` and `Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y` return `1500,1000` but my screen is `3000,2000` scaled by `200%`

the result of this error is an Image with size 1500,1000 from the top left corner.

how i worked around is by simply multiplying the dimensions by 2, but i dont want to hard code this scale factor, i somehow want to get it indevidually.

i also tried this, but this registry entry simply doesnt exist on my computer: 
[Get scale of screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32607468/get-scale-of-screen)

[here the 2 screenshots, 1. what i want 2. what i get](http://glascake.com/stackoverflow/?dir=screen%20scale)

my current code:

```
            int boundsX = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X * 2;
            int boundsY = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y * 2;
            Size screenSize = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size;
            screenSize = new Size(screenSize.Width * 2, screenSize.Height * 2);

            int boundsWidth = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width * 2;
            int boundsHeight = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height * 2;

            // Create a new bitmap.
            var bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap(boundsWidth,
                                boundsHeight,
                                PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

            // Create a graphics object from the bitmap.
            var gfxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot);

            // Take the screenshot from the upper left corner to the right bottom corner.
                gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(boundsX,
                                        boundsY,
                                        0,
                                        0,
                                        screenSize ,
                                        CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
            bmpScreenshot.Save("Screenshot.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

Comment: I have elements scale set to 125% and still `Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds` reports correct display resolution. (Windows 10)

Comment: Trying to undo the dpi virtualization is not the correct fix, you lose info.  Instead just tell the OS that you are a good citizen and don't need to be lied to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228185/how-to-configure-an-app-to-run-correctly-on-a-machine-with-a-high-dpi-setting-e

Comment: @apocalypse i found out, that it works up to 125%, but every thing above wont work.

Comment: DPI virtualization does not have anything to do with forms, it applies to any kind of program.  The only thing you can do wrong is not try it.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977445/how-to-get-windows-display-settings

Comment: @HansPassant thanks that worked just fine!