# VirtualScreenWidth inaccurate dimensions

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this code snippet below:

```
 int screenLeft = (int)SystemParameters.VirtualScreenLeft;
 int screenTop = (int)SystemParameters.VirtualScreenTop;
 int screenWidth = (int)SystemParameters.VirtualScreenWidth;
 int screenHeight = (int)SystemParameters.VirtualScreenHeight;
 
 Bitmap bitmap_Screen = new Bitmap(screenWidth, screenHeight);
 Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap_Screen);
 g.CopyFromScreen(screenLeft, screenTop, 0, 0, bitmap_Screen.Size);
 
 if (!Directory.Exists(screenshotDir))
 {
     Directory.CreateDirectory(screenshotDir);
 }
 bitmap_Screen.Save(fileLoc);
```

I'm trying to take a snapshot of the entire desktop. It's just that `VirtualScreenWidth` and `VirtualScreenHeight` returns 1536 and 800 respectively, when my desktop size is 1920 x 1080. So the snapshot is just capturing a portion of the screen and not an entire screencap

I already found the exact same issue here [Screen Resolution Problem In WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236173/screen-resolution-problem-in-wpf) but being new to WPF and C# in general, I don't understand the selected answer.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your problem is actually in the answer to the question you linked. The dimension you're getting is not pixels, but the WPF "units" that are 1/96". I'm guessing much like in the answer there points out, your screen is at 125% scaling right now, so the formula is exactly the same. 1536 / 96 * 120 = 1920 pixels.

The issue is that you're taking this WPF unit measurement and passing it into a method that needs actual pixels, because it's working not with a WPF element, but the generic Windows screen space. If you also get your current DPI and do the proper math on the values you get from the `VirtualScreenWidth` and other methods you should get a proper screenshot.